# Numbers of the form $2^ma + 2^nb$ where $\text{gcd}(a,b) = 1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given positive integers $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ with ${\text gcd}(a,b) = 1$, and given a positive integer $d$, are there necessarily positive integers $m,n$ such that $d \;| \; (2^ma + 2^nb)$?

Comment: You will need d coprime to a and b. Otherwise an odd prime p could divide d and a, and you are out of luck. If d is coprime to both a and b, a version of the Chinese remainder theorem might work.  Gerhard "The Question Needs More Work" Paseman, 2019.01.16.

Comment: Upon further reflection, an example like Seva's should work. If d is a prime like a Mersenne prime where 2 is far from being a primitive root, there should be coprime a and b such that the divisibility relation fails. I am guessing d=17, a=3 and b=11, but that doesn't work, and I don't see how to save it., d=127 should yield an example.  Gerhard "It's About Powers Of Two" Paseman, 2019.01.16.

Comment: Ah. d=31, a is 3 mod d and b is 5 mod d. We have 2^m times 3 run through 3,6,12,24,17 and  for b we have 5,10,20,9,18. Gerhard "Likes The Power Of Small" Paseman, 2019.01.16.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily: consider the situation where $a=b=1$ and $d$ is a Mersenne prime.

Comment: ...larger than 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a (very unoptimized) SageMath code (which, up to some tweaks, should work in just Python) which brute-forces this (I have taken Gerhard's suggestion from the comments to only include $a,b$ relatively prime to $d$):

```
k = 0
l = 0
for d in range(1,20):
    for a in range(1,d):
        for b in range(1,a+1):
            if gcd(a,b)==1 and gcd(a,d)==1 and gcd(b,d)==1:
                l = l+1
                flag = false
                for m in range(d):
                    for n in range(d):
                        if (2^m*a+2^n*b)%d==0:
                            flag = true
                            break
                    if flag:
                        break
                if not flag:
                    a,b,d
                    k = k+1
k,l
```

within a second the code returns few dozen counterexamples, the smallest of which is $(1,1,7)$ (already indicated in the other answer).

Overall, in the computed range, 61 our of 396 triples are counterexamples. Extending the search up to 100, we get 19889/46522, which means that there are almost as many counterexamples as examples.